# KDE ruined Xfce settings

Tags: kde, configuration, xfce, gtk3

I'm on Archlinux and I recently installed KDE. I use Xfce, but I thought I'd try it to see what's new (still hoping for a KDE3-like with up-to-date Qt). I installed the `plasma-meta` package, it worked, but then I returned to Xfce and, to my horror, this is what my desktop became:

[image: desktop]

As opposed to the behaviour in Thunar:

[image: Thunar]

Since Xfce is now on GTK3, the usual `~/.gtkrc-2.0` no longer works, and the [official documentation](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfdesktop/advanced) is not updated to include a GTK3 solution. I found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/630455/504984) something that tells me `~/.config/gtk3/.gtk.css` might still be usable, somehow, but when I tried brute-hacking these lines, they don't work:

```
.XfdesktopIconView,
.XfdesktopIconView.view:
{
  -XfdesktopIconView-label-alpha: 0;
  -XfdesktopIconView-selected-shadow-color: #2060a0;
  -XfdesktopIconView-ellipsize-icon-labels: 0;
}
```

I tried to look at the source code and, while I can see `ellipsize-icon-labels` in there (at line 536, as it currently is), I don't see anywhere `label-alpha`, or `selected-shadow-color`. So, I don't know whether they were removed or not (the file entry description says: "*Remove redundant code, 11 months ago*").

There seems to be at least one other program affected, `qalkulate-gtk`, but I installed `qalkulate-qt` and it works (I'm more interested in functionality than appearance, but I won't completely discard the latter):

[image: qalculate-gtk]

The blue wasn't there and the result was black font, perfectly readable. But, TBH, this could be a recent upgrade of `qalculate-gtk`, so take a grain of salt with this.

The theme I'm using is an in-house modified version of [Mist-Redmond-Green](https://www.xfce-look.org/p/1150209/), but it worked just fine until KDE. This was the last active theme before starting KDE, and when I returned to Xfce. If I change the theme then the desktop is back to (that theme's) normal, except for `Raleigh` (but I don't remember if I downloaded it, or not. I'd prefer the simplistic Mist, though.

My question: is it known where/what/how does KDE modify settings that affect Xfce (desktop or otherwise)? Alternatively, how/where do I fix this? But I'd rather be the first question, to solve the KDE intrusion.